# how to get small clip of music from complete song

Tags: android

i want to make an application like mp3 cutter. user enter start time and end time and in between that time the music will cut and saved in SD card. s0 plz help me and helpers will definitely get large points.

Comment: take a look at [0xDroid's sound recorder](http://gitorious.org/0xdroid/packages_apps_soundrecorder/blobs/cefd3e81da22167a56c89a8794c9b8dfe67a7673/src/com/android/soundrecorder/Recorder.java).

Answer (score 0):

Already this kind of application available in android market. Why are you going for a new one. If you want to make a new one with additional features mean go for a free mp3 cutter android app include your additional features in it...Google it... lot of free apps available, just crack it...

Comment: how to does crack the app from .apk file?

Comment: @Dinesh: We can able to crack any kind of apk files and use it, But in some software it's most of the file extracted as jar files, we can't able to make a change in it. Also it's not good to say the cracking method in public..

Comment: @intelligentash: cool....Before starting your project better get the free app from net and then make a change in it..Don't waste your time by starting it from the initial stage...All the Best....